# Python matplotlib y axis is not working properly

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a problem with y axis. It works fine until I put too high number into axis function. Here's the code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.available

input_values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
squares = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]

x_values = range(1, 1001)
y_values = [x**2 for x in x_values]

plt.style.use('seaborn')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x_values, y_values, s=100, c=y_values, cmap=plt.cm.Blues)

ax.set_title("Kwadraty liczb", fontsize=24)
ax.set_xlabel("Wartość", fontsize=14)
ax.set_ylabel("Kwadraty wartości", fontsize=14)


ax.axis([0, 1100, 0, 1100000])

plt.show()
```

When i was trying to figure out why it's not working I typed different values into ymax in ax.axis and for example it works for ax.axis([0, 1100, 0 , 10000]) but when I want to get 1100000 this happens https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gSOE.png

Comment: Can you maybe edit your post and include an image of the results you get? It seems to work fine for me

Comment: Hi Lukasz, I've tried your script and it looks good. What is the problem that you have?

Comment: I had a problem with adding a photo so i'll leave a link to it. As u can see on a picture values on y axis are completely different from expected ones.

Comment: I feel like this exact question was asked a week ago. All you need to do add `ax.ticklabel_format(style='plain')`. No custom object is needed.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean that the y axis tick labels are automatically divided by one million (indicated by the "1e6" above the tick labels), you can configure this by creating a custom `ScalarFormatter` object and turning scientific notation off. For more details, see the matplotlib documentation pages [on tick formatters](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/ticks_and_spines/tick-formatters.html) and [on `ScalarFormatter`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import ticker
plt.style.available

input_values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
squares = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]

x_values = range(1, 1001)
y_values = [x**2 for x in x_values]

plt.style.use('seaborn')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x_values, y_values, s=100, c=y_values, cmap=plt.cm.Blues)

ax.set_title("Kwadraty liczb", fontsize=24)
ax.set_xlabel("Wartość", fontsize=14)
ax.set_ylabel("Kwadraty wartości", fontsize=14)

ax.axis([0, 1100, 0, 1100000])

formatter = ticker.ScalarFormatter()
formatter.set_scientific(False)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)

plt.show()
```

Note that I have added a new import statement (`from matplotlib import ticker`) and the three lines above `plt.show()`. If you want this to also apply to the x axis (in case you enlarge this axis), just add a similar line of code: `ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

While you can go through all the extra steps of creating a custom ScalarFormatter object as luuk suggested, you could achieve the same thing by simply configuring what is already provided with `ax.ticklabel_format(style='plain')`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#plt.style.available

input_values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
squares = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]

x_values = range(1, 1001)
y_values = [x**2 for x in x_values]

plt.style.use('seaborn')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.ticklabel_format(style='plain')

ax.scatter(x_values, y_values, s=100, c=y_values,cmap=plt.cm.Blues)

ax.set_title("Kwadraty liczb", fontsize=24)
ax.set_xlabel("Wartość", fontsize=14)
ax.set_ylabel("Kwadraty wartości", fontsize=14)

ax.axis([0, 1100, 0, 1100000])

plt.show()
```

Still results in the same chart desired

[image]

Also, you'll notice I commented out `plt.style.available` because it's useless, being overwritten by `plt.style.use('seaborn')`.